# Как опубликовать iOS-приложение для Apple Business Manager?

Tags: ios, mobile-development, apple

Все как положено - в **App Store Connect** в разделе "**Ценообразование и доступность**" выбран вариант для способа распространения приложения - "**Частное**", и указан Apple ID ABM-аккаунта организации.

**[ABM HELP](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev275598f16)**

С момента опубликования приложения (ready for sale) прошло уже несколько дней - всё уже давно должно было проиндексироваться, но, тем не менее, приложение никак не появляется в Apple Business Manager :(

В ABM не получается найти это приложение, в Profile Manager - тоже.

Написал в техподдержку Apple, пока не ответили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше указывать не Apple ID аккаунта компании, а ID организации (посмотреть его в профиле компании в ABM).  После этого подождать еще час-два.
Потом приложение должно появиться в ABM в разделе «Приложения организации».

Comment: Для установки такого приложения на мобильные устройства через MDM-сервер его все равно надо будет купить в нужном количестве.

Comment: После указания ID организации приложение появилось в ABM (Apple ID ABM-учетки не убирал). Для следующего приложения укажем только ID и проверим результат.